# Loopback three way data binding

Tags: loopback, angular-loopback

I planning to use loopback for my back end. Is it possible to have three way data binding feature in loopback(like firebase).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, Loopback doesn't provide that out of the box, so the simple answer is no.

However, you could accomplish a similar outcome using websockets or a real-time network like [pubnub](https://www.pubnub.com/) or [pusher](https://pusher.com/) for example. Here's a [walkthrough with angular for three-way data binding](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-08-06-angularjs-encryption-and-three-way-binding-tutorial/) from pubnub as a reference.